# Does the React Native fetch() API support caching?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

My app uses fetch(uri, { cache: 'default' }) to query a server and logs the response headers to the console.  When my app fetches with the same URI a second and subsequent times, I would expect to see a status 304, but it continues to respond with 200, even though the response has a cache-control header with a max-age of 86400 (1 day).

I noticed that the server is using Cloudfare and cf-cache-status is set to "HIT" meaning that it is serving from a CDN, but I wouldn't expect that to stop the fetch API from caching.

Do I need to implement my own custom caching solution if I want to avoid re-fetching the same data more than once?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be great to rely on the `statusCodes` of the api's returned.

Since fetch considers statusCodes `101`, `204`, `205`, or `304` as `null` body status as mentioned [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-status)

There are many parameters and [steps](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch) involved to set the statusCode as `304`, for a `cache-fetch` response which needs to be inspected throughly.

But the main thing to note is

*Fetch will inspect the HTTP cache on the way to the network. If there is a fresh response it will be used. If there is a stale response a conditional request will be created, and a normal request otherwise. It then updates the HTTP cache with the response.*

Therefore you can check for the following tags  `If-Modified-Since`, `If-None-Match`, `If-Unmodified-Since`, `If-Match`, or `If-Range`, if they are set then it will automatically set the `cache mode` to `nostore`

Comment: According to the docs, if cache-mode is "default", then the fetch() should not even make a request but return the resource from an internal cache.  But I would like a way to confirm that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Short Story: React Native is caching

Long Story:

Observation:

- My server returns an ETag, but fetch() or XMLHttpRequest always returns status 200 even if the file didn't change
- If I send the ETag manually with the request, fetch() returns status 304 if the file didn't change: fetch(url, {'If-None-Match': etag})
- Tested on android and iOS

I've two Problems:

1. I don't want unnecessary traffic
2. I don't want to rerender my App if the data didn't change

In the past I reinvented the wheel: persisted the ETag and send it with the request. It solved both problems.

I've installed a proxy App. It showed that RN is sending the ETag to the server and the server responses with an empty body + status 304. fetch() returns 200. So yes, it caches the files! But you will never know in your App.

Conclusion

- Good: React Native caches files and there won't be unnecessary traffic.
- Bad: You will never know if it's from the cache, because 304 is mapped to 200. This is a huge problem if you don't want to rerender your App on every request. You have to implement a custom solution for this (save and compare ETag manually or compare old and previous data in some way)